# How can I connect and use my samsung laptop as a second screen for my Macbook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

How can I connect and use my samsung laptop as a second screen for my Macbook Pro? Is such a thing possible? 
Also, if its possible, how do I select which computer should be master/slave?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, but no proper way. The only option is essentially screen sharing via local network. Haven't tried it from mac to pc, but I believe [Air Display 2](https://avatron.com/applications/air-display/) can do that.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [Synergy](https://symless.com/synergy)? It's not exactly a second screen persay, rather mouse/keyboard sharing, but it might be useful depending on your use case.